# Condition to test if string has numeric character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I test if the string has atleast one numerical character rather than test if the whole string is a number?

This is the current code. It works in the following scenarios:
If there is one integer e.g. "43" will display the text corresponding to row 43 in the DB.
If there is a plain text e.g. "None" will display the label "none"

When I have more than one integer comma seperates e.g. "43,82" it will display as "43,82" instead of the corresponding rows.

Jquery:

```
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(gestures[gesture_key].confirming)) && isFinite(gestures[gesture_key].confirming)){
    var confirming = gestures[gesture_key].confirming.split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<confirming.length;i++){
        // Find the name of the gesture
        for(var j=0;j<gestures.length;j++){
            if(gestures[j].id == confirming[i]){
                var gesture_name_key = j;
                var absense = false;
            }
            if(gestures[j].id == -1 * confirming[i]){
                var gesture_name_key = j;
                var absense = true;
            }
        }
        if(!absense) {
            $("ul#confirming_gestures").append("<li class=\"gesture\" value="+confirming[i]+">"+gestures[gesture_name_key].name+"</li>");
        }
        if(absense) {
            $("ul#confirming_gestures").append("<li class=\"gesture\" value="+confirming[i]+">Absense of "+gestures[gesture_name_key].name+"</li>");
        }
    }
} else {
    $("ul#confirming_gestures").append("<li>"+gestures[gesture_key].confirming+"</li>");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple way to test for the presence of at least one numerical character:

```
/\d/.test("asdf");  // false
/\d/.test("as3df"); // true
/\d/.test("12345"); // true
```

So to generalize, you can run any javascript variable and get a boolean result.

```
if(/\d/.test(input)) {
   alert('has at least one digit');
}
```